# Variable for date which is used mutliple times in query script

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d5640c46b1f6ac88b0611f693858c2b6)**

```
CREATE TABLE PaL (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO PaL 
(event_date) 
VALUES 

('2020-01-01'),
('2020-02-05'),
('2020-08-10'),
('2020-12-31');
```

---

I want to run a query in which I have to use the **same date multiple times** looking like this:

```
SELECT 
('2021-01-01' - pl.event_date) AS column_01,
DATEADD(day, +5, '2021-01-01')::date AS column_02,
DATEADD(month, -2, '2021-01-01')::date AS column_03
FROM PaL pl;
```

Therefore, it would be good to be able to use this date as variable. 
The same way it is done here: **[MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f6ed4340401b2134977126e5f47fab19)**.

As far as I know there are no variables in redshift but maybe there is another way of solving the issue. 
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Redshift doesn't have generated columns.  You can use a view, however:

```
CREATE VIEW v_pal as
    SELECT pl.*
           ('2021-01-01' - pl.event_date) AS column_01,
           DATEADD(day, +5, '2021-01-01')::date AS column_02,
           DATEADD(month, -2, '2021-01-01')::date AS column_03
    FROM PaL pl;
```

Or, if you just want this in a single query, you can use a CTE:

```
with params as (
      select '2021-01-01'::date as selected_date
     )
select (p.selected_date - pl.event_date) AS column_01,
       dateadd(day, +5, p.selected_date )::date AS column_02,
       dateadd(month, -2, p.selected_date )::date AS column_03
from params p cross join
     PaL pl
```

Answer (score 0):

Redshift has the SYSDATE() function that returns the start time of the current transaction.  As oppose to GETDATE() which returns the time of the current statement.  If you use SYSDATE() and have your queries in the same transaction, they will be using the same timestamp.